# Converting varchar column to date column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to change column type from VARCHAR2 to DATE. The column is already storing dates in correct format. So I was trying to do something like this

```
alter INM_INCIDENT rename column INM_I_REACTION_TIME to INM_I_REACTION_TIME_OLD;
alter table INM_INCIDENT add INM_I_REACTION_TIME date;
update INM_INCIDENT set INM_I_REACTION_TIME = to_date(INM_I_REACTION_TIME_OLD);
alter table INM_INCIDENT drop column INM_I_REACTION_TIME_OLD;
```

But I've got error on the line with update statement, so my question is, is there any nice solution for copying varchar to date like this?

Comment: In what format is your string date?

Comment: It looks like this `2007-07-10 15:01:03`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update:

```
update INM_INCIDENT set INM_I_REACTION_TIME = to_date(INM_I_REACTION_TIME_OLD, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

You have to adjust the string `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` to your date format in your string date column.